# Create a datafactory pipeline for the below condition without using dataflow activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I have a data in Azure datalake I need to create a pipeline to set it in the required format given below and load it in the datalake ( in my case destination is an API ) without using dataflow transformation.

sample input text file:

| BannerNumber | StoreGroupNumber | StoreGroupName | MemberNumber | MemberName | StoreNumbers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | 83 | SD | 225 | SD2 | 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 93 |

After SD2 remaining all are Storenumbers column values.

Required json output:

```
{
  "BannerNumber": "21",
  "StoreGroupNumber": "83",
  "StoreGroupName": "SD",
  "StoreGroupMembers": [
    {
      "MemberId": "225",
      "MemberLabel": "SD2",
      "StoreNumbers": [
        {
          "StoreId": "5"
        },
        {
          "StoreId": "10"
        },
        {
          "StoreId": "20"
        },
        {
          "StoreId": "30"
        },
        {
          "StoreId": "40"
        },
        {
          "StoreId": "41"
        },
        {
          "StoreId": "42"
        },
        {
          "StoreId": "43"
        },
        {
          "StoreId": "44"
        },
        {
          "StoreId": "93"
        }
      ],
      "MemberAddedOn": "2023-10-23 14:09:29.0430000" <-- Needs to be todays date
    }
  ]
}
```

With dataflow i have done but as per the requirement they need it without using the dataflow

Please help me on this...

Comment: Anyone please suggest me a solution for this

Comment: Ask ChatGPT, I just did and it pretty much gives you the answer.

Comment: Could you please post the json which you have done.

Comment: Nope, not allowed here and it's not JSON, it's the SQL statement that will get you the end result.  Just ask ChatGPT .... simple!

Comment: I will post this in chatGpt and let you know if any doubts...please help if any doubts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use expressions to rearrange data to your format.

Source data (in delimited format by |):

```
BannerNumber|StoreGroupNumber|StoreGroupName|MemberNumber|MemberName|StoreNumbers
21|83|SD|225|SD2|5,10,20,30,40,41,42,43,44,93
```

Use a lookup activity to get the rows from the text file, and then foreach to iterate on the rows (in this example only one row):
[image: main pipeline]

I use a set variable to enter the expression to create the JSON format you wanted:

```
'{
  "BannerNumber": "@{item().BannerNumber}",
  "StoreGroupNumber": "@{item().StoreGroupNumber}",
  "StoreGroupName": "@{item().StoreGroupName}",
  "StoreGroupMembers": [
    {
      "MemberId": "@{item().MemberNumber}",
      "MemberLabel": "@{item().MemberName}",
      "StoreNumbers": [ 
      @{concat('{"StoreId":"',replace(item().StoreNumbers,',','"},{"StoreId":"'),'"}')}
        ],
      "MemberAddedOn": "@{utcnow()}" 
    }
  ]
  }'
```

And the results:

[image: results]